# Cygwin 'grep' in files takes forever

Tags: linux, windows-xp, bash, cygwin, grep

I tried using Cygwin to emulate some cool Linux search feature, and when I do grep in files (12 text files - not big) it takes forever. I used

```
grep -rne word
```

I could find this word faster manually (even without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>). Is there any reason this does not work? How to fix it?

P.S.: I use the Cygwin console.

Comment: Try grep -rne word *
This * should not be necessary, but it work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to tell `grep` *where* to search, so it just sits there waiting for data to be input from 'stdin' – often a pipe, but in this case your keyboard. You can confirm by entering something like "`this is a word`", <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to search the current directory, recursively, give **`.`** as the path.

```
grep -rne word .
```

(Note 2012-07: The latest version of GNU *grep* will search the current directory automatically if `-r` is given.)

---

In many cases, `*` will work too, but it is not recommended because 1) it is inefficient – expanding the wildcard to all file names takes some time and might even overflow the permitted command line length; 2) it does not match dotfiles (names starting with a dot) in most shells, although I'm not sure if this applies to expansion done by Cygwin itself.

Comment: Expansion of wildcards is handled by the shell, and Cygwin uses bash by default.  It works the same way as on Linux or Unix systems.

Comment: Be careful.  `grep -rne word . > grep.out` will include `grep.out` in the files being searched, and will run until you run out of disk space.

Comment: @Keith: Cygwin programs can be run from `cmd.exe` and PowerShell as well, in which case the expansion has to be done by the program itself (or by the Cygwin runtime).

Comment: @grawity Yep, the Cygwin DLL does that if a Cygwin program is invoked from outside Cygwin.